# Usage of なんて in this sentence

Tags: usage, meaning

”正直友達が死んだらこんなにへこむなんておもってみなかった”

I cant understand this sentence.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @sawa: The question is: “What question should I ask?”

Comment: I thought the qeustions was: What is the usage of なんて in this sentence? Which Chocolate had no problem answering. Why is it so difficult for you two?

Comment: +1 for dotnetN00b's comment and the original question. The question is obvious. Please don't forget that we may be dealing with non-native speakers of both English *and* Japanese, or simply people who aren't linguistically agile enough to be able to formulate a question more complex than "I don't understand なんて in this sentence". And there's nothing wrong with that, if that *is* the intended question.

Answer (score 3):

Lol, yeah what is the question.

正直=honestly

友達が=my friend

死んだら=if...dies

こんなに=so much

へこむ=get depressed

なんておもってみなかった=Never did I imagine (that I would...)

P.S. Grammatically it should be '思って"も"みなかった'.

P.P.S  Oops, you were just asking about 'なんて'？

Comment: Ok... so how is なんて being used in the sentence? What is its meaning?

Comment: @dotnetN00b-san, This なんて can be replaced by と/とは/などとは/だろうとは, so the OP can be rephrased like 友達が死んだらこんなにへこむ'と/とは/などとは/だろうとは'思っていなかった. I think this と etc. is working as 'that' in 'I think that~~/I didn't imagine that~~'. なんて/などとは/だろうとは sounds like they carry a nuance of surprise. (And I think the は is added only when the sentence is negative.)

Comment: Maybe this particular question should be moved to Meta, but is my question to you really that different than the OP's original question? I don't say this to be snarky or rude, but I honestly see no difference between our questions.